# NameError issue when trying to call a class method

Tags: python, function, class

Specifically having issues with using a class and calling it.
Its a highest-sum-path of a triangle program.. but I am having issues with my class and calling functions.

specifically..

```
class TriArray():
     triangle = read_input("inputt.txt")
     def get_data(node):
         return triangle[node.row][node.col]
def main():
      triangle = TriArray()

node = triangle.get_root()         #*added these to the question
path_sum = triangle.get_data()


def read_input(filename):           #*so you can see
  triangle = []
  with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
      rows = fin.readline()
      for line in fin:
          for word in rows.split():
              triangle.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
              print(triangle)
```

error is saying triangle is not defined.
where might my mistake be? There are plenty more functions in this class. But this is the current error I am on, Thanks.
list is like

```
[[1],
[1 2],
[1 2 3]]
```

if its relevant..

Comment: Also I have spent hours googling and searching. Please don't think I just immediately came here to post this.

Comment: Make an object of the class first

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add in my main function I have triangle = TriArray()

Comment: Please feel free to edit this into the question; it changes the answer. Also, is the `path_sum = triangle.get_data()` line in the main function as well? If so, the `NameError` should not occur. By the way, what do you mean by "main function", is that the block where you test `"if __name__ == '__main__':"` or a real `def main():` function?

Comment: @johndoe, should `inputt.txt` only have numbers, and are you intentionally skipping the first row? If I use the list you suggest I get a `ValueError` when trying to evaluate `int("[1")`.

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues in your code.

- You should define `triangle` like `triangle = TriArray()`
- `get_data` needs `node` parameter but you are not sending.
- You are missing self parameter.
- `read_input` is not defined.

You can fix like this,

```
class TriArray():
   triangle = None 

   def read_input(self):
     with open('inputt.txt', 'r') as f:
        self.triangle = f.read()

   def get_data(self, node):
     self.read_input()
     return self.triangle[node.row][node.col]

triangle = TriArray()
# you have to define and sent node parameter
# node = ??
path_sum = triangle.get_data(node)
```

Comment: I tried my best to cut down the code to be simple, I asked this before and got reemed for it being too long. Node is defined previous as is the read_input, I suppose I will edit in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class TriArray():
     triangle = read_input("inputt.txt")
     def get_data(node):
         return triangle[node.row][node.col]

triangle = TriArray()
path_sum = triangle.get_data()
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that in my main I have triangle = TriArray()

Comment: @johndoe Please update the question with full base code

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a class method you must instantiate it first:

```
path_sum = TriArray().get_data(node)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not created an instance of the class. The class part of your code only defines a class, but does not instantiate it.

Create an instance by inserting

```
triangle = TriArray()
```

before the last line.

Edit: in your revised code you create an instance in the main function. However, that instance is not visiblke outside the main function. You must create the instance at the same scope as where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class like this, that's fine. But without an actual instance of the class, `triangle` will remain an internal value that is not defined outside. That's why there is a `NameError`.

Based on your edits, we see that there is an instantiation. But this takes place inside a `main` function; the other lines outside this function still don't see it.

One way is to put the `path_sum` inside the `main` function, as shown here:

```
class TriArray():

    def get_data(node):
        return triangle[node.row][node.col]

    def read_input(filename):
        triangle = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
            rows = fin.readline()
            for line in fin:
                for word in rows.split():
                    triangle.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
                    print(triangle)

    triangle = read_input("inputt.txt")

def main():
    # let's assume node is defined and node.row = 0, node.col = 1
    triangle = TriArray()
    path_sum = triangle.get_data(node) # brought in from the cold
```

This means, of course, that for anything to happen, you'd need to actually invoke the `main` function. You'll also notice that I've shifted `read_input` into the class and before it is invoked, so that there will not be a `NameError` when trying to invoke `read_input`.